# GTX1070 HDMI driver crashes

Tags: windows-10, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

So, basically after clean install of Windows 10, I found out that my screen isn't working with it properly.

The screen is perfectly fine when connected over HDMI with my Laptop, however when connecting it to the desktop PC over same HDMI cable, is works with a bit of pixel loss (weird yellow/blue pixels distorting some of the image, the color is basically the negative of the color it's supposed to show, sort of inverted, a picture of it is available [**HERE**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp9sB.jpg)) for a few minutes then black screen. After reviewing the device Event log, it seems there's an issue causing it to crash, the log says "Device install required - Requieres further installation". Another monitor works fine when connected to the GPU with DVI. HDMI port seems fine to me and based on situation. It seems to me that it's strictly the HDMI Driver.

I've tried uninstalling the driver with DDU twice with a restart, just in-case to make sure the driver is completely gone.
I've performed clean install of the latest Geforce driver and it's still the same.
When no geforce driver is installed (therefore relying on the native Windows basic display driver), thte HDMI doesn't work completely.

Any idea of how this can be fixed? RMA isn't an option since it quite past the time frame for it, also the GPU doesn't seems to be the issue, but rather the HDMI port's driver.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

[image]